# Unclear instructions in Angular Hero Editor project

Tags: angular

[The tutorial for Angular Hero Editor](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt1#add-a-hero-property) states that to add a hero property to the HeroesComponent for a hero named "Windstorm" you should edit heroes.component.ts and add:
hero = 'Windstorm';

However, it does not say where the code should be placed.

Where should I add the code to the file? Below is the contents of the file:

```
 import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
 @Component({
 selector: 'app-heroes',
 templateUrl: './heroes.component.html',
 styleUrls: ['./heroes.component.css']
})
export class HeroesComponent implements OnInit {

 constructor() { 

 }

 ngOnInit() {
}

}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Make `hero = 'Windstorm';` a property of the component.

```
export class HeroesComponent implements OnInit {
  hero = 'Windstorm';

  constructor() {    
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
export class HeroesComponent implements OnInit {
 hero: Hero = {
 id: 1,
  name: 'Windstorm'
  };
```

This is how you do it.